# Performing sliding 4-neighborhood operations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nearest-neighbor

Is there a method to perform custom operations in an image with a given neighborhood?.

For example, I've defined two functions `fmax = @(x)max(x(:))` and `fmin = @(x)min(x(:))` to calculate the gradient of a gray scale image `I` as:

`G = nlfilter(I,[3 3],fmax) - nlfilter(I,[3 3],fmin);`

However, I would like do the same with a 4-neighborhood instead of the 8-neighborhood defined in the 3-by-3 sliding block, in a similar way as the structuring elements that are used in morphological mathematical.

The idea behind this test is apply a custom function to a pixel and a given neighborhood with a radius `r`.

Note that I'm interested in apply user defined functions. The gradient is just an example.

Comment: Have a look at blockproc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous function ***is*** the "user defined" or "custom" function you are after.

You just need to use the anonymous function according to your needs. 
For example, in order to consider only the 4 nearest neighbors (up down left right) pixels for a 3x3 window you can write:

```
f = @(x) max(x(2:2:8)) - min(x(2:2:8)) 
G = nlfilter(I,[3 3],f);
```

as the gradient.

Another example, to do the same for a generic circular neighborhood of radius `r`:

```
r = 5;
H = fspecial('disk',r);
f = @(x) max(x(H>0))-min(x(H>0)); 
G = nlfilter(I,size(H),f);
```

Comment: thanks for your code natan! I'm trying to optimize a function that is taking to much time to compute and it's based on circular neighboorhoods. More precisely, I've different circular neighboorhoods and inside of each of them, I want to compute the mean, std, and median of the pixel values underlying them. This is done in the context of the DoG scale representation. The size of the circular filter is given by radius associated at a specific scale (`scalespace_radii`): http://pastebin.com/WkS5ShMf Any suggestion on how to improve the computation is welcomed!

Comment: Why won't you ask a question, so the entire community can help with this?

Comment: Hi Natan, I'm trying to come with a solution, that it's based on your current proposal for circular neighborhoods. I'm trying basically, to compute efficiently histograms inside circular regions. Do you mind in having a look at => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750989/matlab-efficient-computation-of-local-histograms-within-circular-neighboorhoods