# matlab: efficient computation of local histograms within circular neighboorhoods

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, image-processing, histogram

I've an image over which I would like to compute a local histogram within a circular neighborhood. The size of the neighborhood is given by a `radius`. Although the code below does the job, it's computationally expensive. I run the profiler and the way I'm accessing to the pixels within the circular neighborhoods is already expensive.

Is there any sort of improvement/optimization based maybe on vectorization? Or for instance, storing the neighborhoods as columns?
I found a similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233949/circular-neighborhood-operations-matlab-color-histogram) and the proposed solution is quite in the spirit of the code below, however the solution is still not appropriate to my case. Any ideas are really welcomed :-) Imagine for the moment, the image is binary, but the method should also ideally work with gray-level images :-)

```
[rows,cols] = size(img);
hist_img      = zeros(rows, cols, 2);
[XX, YY]      = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);
for rr=1:rows
        for cc=1:cols
            distance      = sqrt( (YY-rr).^2 + (XX-cc).^2  );
            mask_radii = (distance <= radius);
            bwresponses   = img(mask_radii);
            [nelems, ~]   = histc(double(bwresponses),0:255);
            % do some processing over the histogram
            ...
        end
end
```

**EDIT 1** Given the received feedback, I tried to update the solution. However, it's not yet correct

```
radius = sqrt(2.0);
disk   = diskfilter(radius);
fun    = @(x) histc( x(disk>0), min(x(:)):max(x(:)) ); 
output = im2col(im, size(disk), fun);

function disk = diskfilter(radius)
    height  = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
    width   = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
    [XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:width,1:height);
    dist    = sqrt((XX-ceil(width/2)).^2+(YY-ceil(height/2)).^2);
    circfilter = (dist <= radius);
end
```

Comment: when the speed really matters, i would mex c function for it

Comment: maybe try `blockproc` with block size of `radius`, and compute the histogram only on the inscribed circle in each block.

Comment: I second the blockproc suggestion, but also you only have to calculate the circle once for the top corner and then just shift it around. So you'll have a `mask` which is just a corner version of your `mask_gt_radii` and then each loop just `circshift(mask, [0,1])` for column iterations and `circshift(mask,[1,0])` for row iterations. Then you'll just need to handle edge cases, probably with zero padding.

Comment: @Adiel, I tried to follow your suggestion. But I'm not sure, if I got the idea correctly. Do you mind in having a look into my updated post?

Comment: @Dan, do you mind in given an example of what you're suggesting? I updated my original post.

Comment: Watch it, block processing is not the same as a moving filter.

Comment: @Jigg is correct. Based on what you're doing in your first attempt you probably should use `colfilt` or `im2col` instead.

Comment: As a side note, there is a simpler way of generating a circular filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20002170/2777181

Comment: @Jigg: It is a simple function, but the shape of that isn't quite the same because of how it's made. If you look at the internals it's doing all sorts of extra stuff.

Comment: For binary images you simply have to add the image to N different places, where N is the number of pixels in the circular kernel. For gray-level, the number of (matrix) operations is N*(Q-1) where Q is the number of quantization levels.

Comment: @horchler I agree. I should have mentioned that it's just simpler in terms of characters to be typed.

Comment: @horchler, thanks for the feedback. after however, doing `im2col` the method does not work yet. One thing, is how to properly store the `result` after applying `im2col`. Furthermore, do you have a suggestion how to re-arrange the image to columns based on the circular neighborhoods? Each column will contain the circular neighbors of a given pixel.

Comment: @Jigg, thanks for the suggestion on how to improve the circular filter!

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, do you mind in illustrating your solution?

Comment: What is a typical value for `radius`?

Comment: I am pretty sure this would answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21464505/376454

Answer (score 1):

You're right, I don't think that `colfilt` can be used as you're not applying a filter. You'll have to check the correctness, but here's my attempt using [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) and your `diskfilter` function (I did remove the conversion to `double` so it now output logicals):

```
function circhist

% Example data
im = randi(256,20)-1;

% Ranges - I do this globally for the whole image rather than for each neighborhood
mini = min(im(:));
maxi = max(im(:));
edges = linspace(mini,maxi,20);

% Disk filter
radius = sqrt(2.0);
disk = diskfilter(radius); % Returns logical matrix

% Pad array with -1
im_pad = padarray(im, (size(disk)-1)/2, -1);

% Convert sliding neighborhoods to columns
B = im2col(im_pad, size(disk), 'sliding');

% Get elements from each column that correspond to disk (logical indexing)
C = B(disk(:), :);

% Apply histogram across columns to count number of elements
out = histc(C, edges)

% Display output
figure
imagesc(out)
h = colorbar;
ylabel(h,'Counts');
xlabel('Neighborhood #')
ylabel('Bins')
axis xy

function disk = diskfilter(radius)
height  = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
width   = 2*ceil(radius)+1;
[XX,YY] = meshgrid(1:width,1:height);
dist    = sqrt((XX-ceil(width/2)).^2+(YY-ceil(height/2)).^2);
disk = (dist <= radius);
```

If you want to set your ranges (`edges`) based on each neighborhood then you'll need to make sure that the vector is always the same length if you want to build a big matrix (and then the rows of that matrix won't correspond to each other).

You should note that the shape of the disk returned by `fspecial` is not as circular as what you were using. It's meant to be used a smoothing/averaging filter so the edges are fuzzy (anti-aliased). Thus when you use `~=0` it will grab more pixels. It'd stick with your own function, which is faster anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @horchler! I was having a look at it, especially between the steps from matrix `B` to matrix `C`. Given the results, it looks like the neighborhoods are not centered. Given for instance a neighborhood of [3,3] and a pixel at (x,y) it looks for the following neighborhood: `(x:x+3,y:y+3)`, instead of `(x-1:x+1,y-1:y+1)`. I think, maybe a padding could help? But then, the thing would be how to remove those padded new pixels, when computing the column-wise histogram?

Comment: @Tin: If you read the help for `im2col` it clearly states that it does no zero padding when the `'sliding'` option is used. Your question didn't define what should happen at the edges anyways. It's pretty easy to  pad `im` with the right number of zeros before though – see [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html).

Comment: @Tin: It's also possible that the `disk` matrix simply needs to be transposed before `disk(:)` is applied in order for the indices to correspond correctly.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @horchler. I think, since the `disk` is symmetric, it shouldn't be needed to transpose it. Furthermore, yes, the padding is easy to make. My idea, so as to have column-vectors of the same size, was to pad the image with e.g. `-1` in the borders, then when computing the column-wise histogram only to look for the positive pixel values, something like: `out = histc(C(C>0), edges);`, where C is a columnwise-matrix after having padded the image with `-1` at the borders. The problem is that the masking I'm doing `(C>0)` loses the shape of the matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tin: I've added padding with `-1` to my answer. `histc` won't count elements with that values as long the range of `edges` doesn't contain it. I also added the version of `diskfilter` I'm using. I'm not sure you need to do any thing else. However, I still don't know what you're trying to count with your histogram. Your problem isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Following on the technique I described in my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464505/1967396) you could try to do the following:

1. compute the index offsets from a particular voxel that get you to all the neighbors within a radius
2. Determine which voxels have all neighbors at least radius away from the edge
3. Compute the neighbors for all these voxels
4. Generate your histograms for each neighborhood

It is not hard to vectorize this, but note that

1. It will be slow when the neighborhood is large
2. It involves generating an intermediate matrix that is NxM (N = voxels in image, M = voxels in neighborhood) which could get very large

Here is the code:

```
% generate histograms for neighborhood within radius r
A = rand(200,200,200);
radius = 2.5;
tic
sz=size(A);
[xx yy zz] = meshgrid(1:sz(2), 1:sz(1), 1:sz(3));
center = round(sz/2);
centerPoints = find((xx - center(1)).^2 + (yy - center(2)).^2 + (zz - center(3)).^2 < radius.^2);
centerIndex = sub2ind(sz, center(1), center(2), center(3));

% limit to just the points that are "far enough on the inside":
inside = find(xx > radius+1 & xx < sz(2) - radius & ...
    yy > radius + 1 & yy < sz(1) - radius & ...
    zz > radius + 1 & zz < sz(3) - radius);

offsets = centerPoints - centerIndex;
allPoints = 1:prod(sz);
insidePoints = allPoints(inside);
indices = bsxfun(@plus, offsets, insidePoints);

hh = histc(A(indices), 0:0.1:1);  % <<<< modify to give you the histogram you want
toc
```

A 2D version of the same code (which might be all you need, and is considerably faster):

```
% generate histograms for neighborhood within radius r
A = rand(200,200);
radius = 2.5;
tic
sz=size(A);
[xx yy] = meshgrid(1:sz(2), 1:sz(1));
center = round(sz/2);
centerPoints = find((xx - center(1)).^2 + (yy - center(2)).^2  < radius.^2);
centerIndex = sub2ind(sz, center(1), center(2));

% limit to just the points that are "far enough on the inside":
inside = find(xx > radius+1 & xx < sz(2) - radius & ...
    yy > radius + 1 & yy < sz(1) - radius);

offsets = centerPoints - centerIndex;
allPoints = 1:prod(sz);
insidePoints = allPoints(inside);
indices = bsxfun(@plus, offsets, insidePoints);

hh = histc(A(indices), 0:0.1:1);  % <<<< modify to give you the histogram you want
toc
```

Comment: @Wok - yes, this was in part in response to your comment in the other answer I had posted!

Comment: @Floris, thank you for your posting. From what I understood, the histogram is not computed in the neighborhoods, where the window does not completely fit in (`points far enough on the inside`), right? Would it be possible to compute the histogram, also including those pixels at the borders? In this case, the histogram should be computed only for the valid/existing pixels and dismissing for instance `padded` pixels?

Comment: What is the meaning of buidling an histogram if there is only one value for instance?

Comment: @wok - Usually you use a histogram to get a sense of the distribution of values - in particular, outliers etc for non-Gaussian distributions. As the number of points gets smaller, the histogram stops being valuable. With a single point, it has no value that I can think of.

Comment: @Floris Hence, I believe histograms should be only built for complete neighborhoods.

Comment: @wok why do you think I wrote the example for complete neighborhoods only (apart from "it is easier")?...

Answer (score 0):

You could try processing with an opposite logic (as briefly explained in the comment)

```
hist = zeros(W+2*R, H+2*R, Q);
for i = 1:R+1;
  for j = 1:R+1;  
      if ((i-R-1)^2+(j-R-1)^2 < R*R)
         for q = 0:1:Q-1;
             hist(i:i+W-1,j:j+H-1,q+1) += (image == q);
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: 3 for loops. Isn't that worse then what OP has?

Comment: Depends on the dimensions. When Q*N is small, this beast will fly. When W*H is large, cache penalties could be avoided by block striping.